# WPF DataGrids in itemsControl with shared Column sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, size, datagridcolumn

Ok, I need to refactor other one's code and I cannot change it too much.
So the problem is the following,
there is an ItemsControl with StackPanel as its ItemsPanel.
Inside we have DataTemplates, each of them has a DataGrid (it needs to stay that way, so redoing it as DataGrid with grouping is out of the question).
Now, the DataGrid has 2 columns. First of them is kinda Auto, second is *.
The first ones should share their width.

The DG columns look something like this:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ItemPropertyNameColumn" 
                      CellTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyGridNameColumnTemplate}"
                      Width="Auto"
                      MaxWidth="145"/>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ItemPropertyValueColumn" 
                      CellTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyGridValueColumnTemplate}"
                      Width="1*"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Inside of a cell is a TextBlock (don't ask...), must stay that way.

Comment: OK but what's the question?

Comment: I would put an invisible grid at the top level and bind both to that.

Comment: @Sach "The first ones should share their width."

Comment: @Bizhan I tried it as an invisible grid inside of the template, and the grid on top level (where ItemsControl is) would be IsSharedSizeScope = true, but it didn't help.

Comment: @AleksandarTrifunović that's not what I suggested. Columns and rows participating in size sharing do not respect Star sizing. In this scenario, Star sizing is treated as Auto.

Comment: @Bizhan Could you, please, explain a bit further what you meant?

Comment: have one extra grid at the top level (outside of all the templates) then use binding to bind the width of two columns to the two grids to the actualwidth of the two columns of that one grid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I solved it a bit stranger way, since binding to Grids with SharedSizeScope didn't work in many configurations.

I solved it using a simple DataTemplateColumn as a named resource outside the template and I just bound my first column to the Width of it with Mode - TwoWay.

It's a bit strange, but it worked.